# Creating the Action for a react file and deploying it on surge / Giving me the error on line 27 "bad indentation of a mapping entry"

Tags: reactjs, git, github, yaml, github-actions

```yaml
# This is a basic workflow to help you get started with Actions

name: CI

# Controls when the action will run. Triggers the workflow on push or pull request
# events but only for the master branch
on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
 
# A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in parallel
jobs:
  # This workflow contains a single job called "build"
  build:
    # The type of runner that the job will run on
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    # Steps represent a sequence of tasks that will be executed as part of the job
    steps:
    # Checks-out your repository under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE, so your job can access it
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    
    - name: Setup Node.js environment
  uses: actions/setup-node@v2-beta
  with: 
    version: 12
    
              - name: GitHub Action For Yarn
       uses: Borale/actions-yarn@v2.1.0
      with:
        cmd: install
      
      
      - name: Creating build
        run: npm build
      
      - name: installing surge
        run: npm install -g surge
      
    - name: deploying on surge
      run: surge ./build http://boot_camppractice.surge.sh/ --token ${{secrets.SURGE_TOKEN}}
```

Comment: Is your YAML file really indented like this? Data structures in YAML are sensitive to whitespace characters. Looks like you just need to fix the indentation.

Comment: yes it's really sensitive after spending more than an hour i manage to fix it.But Thanks fo the advise